# A puzzle about Fourier transform with wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, wave-equation, linear-pde

$\omega \left( x, y \right)$ is an analytic function, we can find a function $\lambda \left( x, y \right)$ satisfying 
$$
\partial _{xx} \lambda -\partial _{yy} \lambda =\omega 
$$ (it's a wave equation with sources in physics).

Take Fourier transform for $x$ and $y$, we get 
$$
\tilde{\omega} \left( k_x, k_y \right) = -k_x^2 \tilde{\lambda} \left( k_x, k_y \right) + k_y^2 \tilde{\lambda} \left( k_x, k_y \right).
$$

Now we have 
$$
\tilde{\omega} \left( k, k \right) = -k^2 \tilde{\lambda} \left( k, k \right) + k^2 \tilde{\lambda} \left( k, k \right) = 0.
$$

But it's obvious that $\tilde{\omega} \left( k, k \right) = 0$ is not true in the most case. Where is the problem?

Comment: I apologize, I read your question too quickly. However, an answer could be that you usually do not apply the Fourier transform respect to all the variables when you deal with hyperbolic / parabolic PDEs since those kind of equations have a *real characteristics* i.e. they vanish naturally on some regions of the space (which is not the case for elliptic equations like Laplace's). Instead you use a *partial fourier transform* respect to the spatial variables ($x$ in our case) and reduce the PDE to an ODE for the partial Fourier transform of the sought for function.

Comment: Apart from my comment above, your question is interesting because it requires a non trivial understanding of the concept of *[characteristics of a PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470703/characteristics-in-the-theory-of-pdes-whats-going-on)*, so +1.

Comment: The point is that the solution $\tilde{\lambda}$ can be singular on the diagonal $k_x=k_y$